# check if handle exists

Tags: vb.net, window, handle

i am using this code to detect when a specific window is active, and when it is i save the handle in a variable:

```
    Dim kiosk As IntPtr
    Dim l As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(GetForegroundWindow())
    Dim WindowTextBuffer As String = New String(Chr(0), l)
    GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), WindowTextBuffer, l + 1)

    Debug.WriteLine(WindowTextBuffer)


    If WindowTextBuffer = "FFKiosk" Then
        kiosk = GetForegroundWindow()
    End If
```

so far everything is working fine. But i would like to verify that this window is still active, if not i would like to set the kiosk variable to null. how can i verify if this handle is still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to your specific question is: import the IsWindow function from the User32.dll

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Function IsWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

then,

```
If IsWindow(kiosk) Then
    ' do something
End If
```

But MSDN [warns against that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if your thread isn't the one that created the window: "A thread should not use IsWindow for a window that it
did not create because the window could be destroyed after this
function was called. Further, because window handles are recycled the
handle could even point to a different window."

Instead, better to get the process ID(s) and check if the process(es) is still running.

```
    Dim processes As System.Diagnostics.Process() = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("theExeName")
    Dim processIds(processes.Length) As Integer

    If processes.Length > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each processId As Integer In processIds
            processIds(i) = processes(i).Id
        Next
```